# Bind link list to datagridview

Tags: c#, xml

I tried the code below. I have created link list which name is weather and
 display the data on datagridview. but error occurred('npc'is a variable it used like a method)i have tried many times but i couldn't please fix the error.

this is code i used for created link list

```
LinkedList<string> weather = new LinkedList<string>();

private void getW(string city)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("country", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Max Temp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Min Temp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Maxwindmph", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Maxwindkph", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Humidity", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Cloud", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Icon", typeof(Bitmap));

            city = txttext.Text;

            string uri = string.Format("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?={0}&days=7", city);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(uri);

            LinkedList<string> weather = new LinkedList<string>();

            weather.AddLast ( (string)doc.Descendants("maxtemp_c").FirstOrDefault());
            weather.AddLast  ((string)doc.Descendants("mintemp_c").FirstOrDefault());
            weather.AddLast ( (string)doc.Descendants("maxwind_mph").FirstOrDefault());
            weather.AddLast  ((string)doc.Descendants("maxwind_kph").FirstOrDefault());
            weather.AddLast ((string)doc.Descendants("avghumidity").FirstOrDefault());
            weather.AddFirst ((string)doc.Descendants("text").FirstOrDefault());

         //   foreach (var npc in doc.Descendants("forecastday"))

            foreach (var npc in weather)
            {
                string iconUri = (string)npc("icon").FirstOrDefault();
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                byte[] image = client.DownloadData("http:" + iconUri);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image);

                Bitmap newBitMap = new Bitmap(stream);
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                         (string)doc.Descendants("country").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc("date").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc("maxtemp_c").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc("mintemp_c").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc("maxwind_mph").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc("maxwind_kph").FirstOrDefault(),
                           (string)npc("avghumidity").FirstOrDefault(),

                           (string)npc("text").FirstOrDefault(),
                           newBitMap
                       });
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: (string)npc("date").FirstOrDefault(), link list varibale added here error comimg('npc'is a variable it used like a method)

Comment: `weather` is a `LinkedList<string>` so that means `npc` is a `string`. What do you expect `npc("date")` to mean when `npc` is of type `string`?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says nbc is  a variable, probably you need

```
   (string)doc.Descendants("country").FirstOrDefault(),
   (string)npc["date"].FirstOrDefault()
```

Replace all **`()`** with **`[]`** since tou are accessing the properties

Comment: still error( 'npc'is a variable it used like a method)

Comment: did you replace for all the values

Comment: ya changed the as[ ] brackets  error(the best overload method match for string)

Comment: (string)npc["country"].FirstOrDefault(),error(the best overload method match for string)

Comment: above code how to use link list and feed data please help me